# How to use an existing android project as library/source to other android projects?

Tags: android, templates

I am building series of android projects with almost the same classes, only some sources like images are different.
I want to make it like a source or library, so that I can create projects by only referring to that source/library, inherit the class, and put in images.

For example, I create a project call "Prototype", which is the template. Then I build new projects, adding "Prototype" in Build Path -> projects. Then I extend the classes in "Prototype", it compiles. But when I run it, it says "Could not find Prototype.apk!"

Am I doing correctly? Or I need the Prototype.apk? If so, where should I put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse as the IDE for your Android projects? If so, you can create library projects as described in: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html
You can then use a library project as your Prototype.